# How to use reflection to change the private shared value without instance just type

Tags: vb.net

I have a dll class, it has a shared field .
When it loads ,the null pointer error will happen, because some resource config can not load.

I get the FieldInfo by the Type.
However i can't set the value by
fieldInfo.SetValue(Nothing, value)

Comment: Please provide a complete, reproducible example to illustrate the specific problem, as specified in the Help Center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `Nothing` as the instance to the `SetValue` method

```vb
Public Class Foo
    Private Shared Bar As Integer
    Public Function GetBar() As Integer
        Return Bar
    End Function
End Class
```

```vb
Dim fi = GetType(Foo).GetField("Bar", BindingFlags.Static Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
fi.SetValue(Nothing, 123)
Dim o = New Foo()
Debug.WriteLine(o.GetBar())
```

> 123

From [FieldInfo.SetValue Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.setvalue?view=net-7.0#system-reflection-fieldinfo-setvalue(system-object-system-object)),

> `Public Sub SetValue (obj As Object, value As Object)`
>
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `obj` Object
>
> The object whose field value will be set.
>
>
> `value` Object
>
> The value to assign to the field.
>
>
>  ...
>
>
> **Remarks**
>
> This method will assign value to the field reflected by this instance on object obj. ***If the field is static, obj will be ignored.***